# Azure Devops "You do not have permission to attach files to work items in the current area path."

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to add an attachment to a work item in Azure Devops. I am an administrator for the project and Area path. When I attempt to add an attachment I get the error   "You do not have permission to attach files to work items in the current area path." I have searched and searched but can't figure out which permission I am missing. Does anyone know which permission I should give myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out this morning. One of my coworkers had a theory to try. It appears it is not being allowed when connected to our VPN. When I attempt it with out being connected to the VPN it works as expected. Hope this says someone hours of research.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) after 48 hours-limitation , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce same issue like yours, but I think it's may not a simple permission-related issue.

Check the `project configuration` page and make sure [all related permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path) for specific user are allowed.

Search the user name and try allowing all permissions here and do the test again:

[image]

Then use a edge/chrome browser(after cleaning the cache), sign-out and sign-in the web portal again to check if the issue disappears.